# Python regex to determine whether a character is numeric, alphanumeric or in a specified string

Tags: python, regex

I am unsure as to how one would use a Python regex to determine whether a character is numeric, alphanumeric or in a specified string.

Something like (fake code warning):

```
if 'a' in re.['A-Z']:
   print "Alpha"

if '.' in re.['.,;']:
   print "Punctiation"
```

Comment: `str.isalpha`, `str.isalnum`.

Comment: Thanks but I need a more general solution

Comment: @Superdooperhero. What do you mean by that?

Comment: See my edit for the Punctiation option

Comment: @Superdooperhero You don't need regex here: `'.' in string.punctuation`

Comment: please add tags for python2.x or python3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`match`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=match#re.match) function from module [`re`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re

x = 'a'
if re.match('[a-zA-Z]', x):
    print "Alpha"
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I add re.VERBOSE + re.UNICODE to that?

Comment: @Superdooperhero: `re.match('[a-zA-Z]', x, re.VERBOSE+re.UNICODE)`. Did you notice that both `match` and `re` in the first line of the reply are also links? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.isalpha()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) method:

```
>>> 'a'.isalpha()
True
```

For testing single character for punctuation or alphanumeric, you can use constants pre-defined in [`string`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) module:

```
>>> '.' in string.punctuation:
True
```